# Why does this return True within the 'for' loop override the return False at the end of the function?

Tags: python

[image]

Help! Why does Out[14] print True although i placed return False at the end of the function has_33(nums)?

Comment: because the condition is satisfied and you return True, exiting the function and not allowing the loop to complete

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Line 4 has a `return True` and is triggered by the if statement above it. When a python function hits the first return, it... well returns w/o going further.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_return.asp `The return keyword is to exit a function and return a value.`

Answer (score 1):

Because the 'return' keyword ends the function on the spot.

'Return' keyword exits a function so in your case the 'return False' does not even run.